# Compare two slices and delete the unique values in Golang

Tags: arrays, go

I have this but it is not working properly :

```golang
var i int
var names = []string{"F5", "F7", "C6", "H5", "G5"}
var board = []string{"B4", "D4", "G5", "F5", "F7", "C6"}

for i = 0; i < len(names)-1; i++ {
    for k := 0; k < len(board)-1; k++ {
        if names[i] != board[k] {
            names = append(names[:i], names[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
}
fmt.Printf("%s ", names[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the intersection of two slices (delete the unique values from the first slice), try this working sample code (and notice the `i++`):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    names := []string{"F5", "F7", "C6", "H5", "G5"}
    board := []string{"B4", "D4", "G5", "F5", "F7", "C6"}
    for i := 0; i < len(names); {
        exist := false
        for _, b := range board {
            if b == names[i] {
                exist = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !exist {
            names = append(names[:i], names[i+1:]...) // delete names[i]
        } else {
            i++
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(names) // [F5 F7 C6 G5]
}
```

output:

```
[F5 F7 C6 G5]
```

Also you may use this for the intersection of two slices with new `result`, try this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    names := []string{"F5", "F7", "C6", "H5", "G5"}
    board := []string{"B4", "D4", "G5", "F5", "F7", "C6"}
    result := make([]string, 0, 11)
    for _, v := range names {
        exist := false
        for _, w := range board {
            if v == w {
                exist = true
                break
            }
        }
        if exist {
            result = append(result, v)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(result) // [F5 F7 C6 G5]
}
```

output:

```
[F5 F7 C6 G5]
```

or if you need The union of two slices, try this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    names := []string{"F5", "F7", "C6", "H5", "G5"}
    board := []string{"B4", "D4", "G5", "F5", "F7", "C6"}
    for _, b := range board {
        exist := false
        for _, n := range names {
            if n == b {
                exist = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !exist {
            names = append(names, b)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(names) // [F5 F7 C6 H5 G5 B4 D4]
}
```

output:

```
[F5 F7 C6 H5 G5 B4 D4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are updating `names` inside your inner `for` loop. However, your inner loop is also logically incorrect. The very first value in `board` not equal to a value in `names` will empty `names`. This also causes an `index out of range` error.

You can try something like this:

```
var names = []string{"F5", "F7", "C6", "H5", "G5"}
var board = []string{"B4", "D4", "G5", "F5", "F7", "C6"}

results := make([]string, 0) // slice tostore the result

for i := 0; i < len(names); i++ {
    for k := 0; k < len(board); k++ {
        if names[i] != board[k] {               
            continue
        }
        // append a value in result only if
        // it exists both in names and board
        results = append(results, names[i])
    }
}
fmt.Printf("%v %d \n", results, len(results))
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/cQpzbvCGpO

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `map` out of one of your arrays and avoid the nested loop, for example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var names = []string{"F5", "F7", "C6", "H5", "G5"}
    var board = []string{"B4", "D4", "G5", "F5", "F7", "C6"}

    var board_map = make(map[string]bool)

    for _, ele := range board {
        board_map[ele] = true
    }

    var result []string

    for _, name := range names {
        if board_map[name] {
            result = append(result, name)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(result)

}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mMrAD3A5ty)

Comment: You're using a map of bools!  Take advantage of the fact that the zero value of a bool is false, and reading a non-existent key from a map returns that type's zero value: https://play.golang.org/p/WYQiUegf8F.

Comment: Unrelated, prefer the `make` or simple variable declaration to the empty literal for maps and slices.  It's more clear, and in the case of the slice, avoids an allocation of the underlying array if the slice is never appended to.

Comment: @Kaedys, Thanks. On the first point you are totally right, I edited my answer to reflect your suggestion. On the second point, I just wanted to be consistent with how the OP was declaring and initializing variables.

Comment: OP was declaring literals because he was initializing them with non-zero values.  Empty literals, on the other hand, tend to be frowned upon a bit by the Go community.  JimB has also chastised me in the past for posting code that is sub-optimal when it's just for the purposes of aligning with the OP's non-idiomatic style.

Comment: @Kaedys, I addressed the second point too. Thanks for pointing it out.